# networkx find_negative_cycle parameters

Tags: python, networkx

What am I supposed to pass as the source parameter to the `find_negative_cycle()` method of the python networkx module? In the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.find_negative_cycle.html) it says to pass a list, but when I try to do so, I get the error:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: can you try send tuple(yourlist) instead

Comment: Then I get the error that the tuple is not a node in my graph

Comment: in the source code the source is used to creat a dict : `pred = {source: []}`, that why you get the unhashable issue

Comment: I noticed that too. Is this a bug in the code or what could I pass in such that the function still does its job?

Comment: does the source should be juste one node?

Comment: Can you try a list of list like  [[node1],[node2],...]

Comment: List of list does not work either, unfortunately. I think I should pass multiple nodes. I did not get a TypeError when I passed a single integer, but the function did not work correctly either.

Comment: I suggest you tu raise an issue on the networkx git https://github.com/networkx

Comment: I will do so. Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the documentation. It should be fixed in version 2.8.1
https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/5610#event-6575071112

Answer (score 0):

you could also try to modify the function itself

https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.py#L2191

in `find_negative_cycle` line 2191

```
pred = {source: []}
v = _inner_bellman_ford(G, [source], weight, pred=pred)
```

with

```
pred = {v: [] for v in sources}
v = _inner_bellman_ford(G, source, weight, pred=pred)
```

if `source` is a list.
I think this issue should be reported

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
def get_sequence_upto(x):
    for i in range(x):
        yield i
        
source = get_sequence_upto([1,2,3])

find_negative_cycle(G, source )
```

where [1,2,3] should be your list of source

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. It then searches for the generator in the graph and that node obviously does not exist.